# Selecting non-existent files with wildcard/regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, regular-expression, arguments

I'm trying to convert hundreds of `*.jpg` files to `*.webp` files with [`libwebp`](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/using) on macOS. Particularly, I want to use the command line tool [`cwebp`](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp) to perform the conversion. It works like this:

```
cwebp <input_file>.jpg -o <output_file>.webp
```

My `*.jpg` files, whose names are `IMG_20160227_110640.jpg` or so, are stored under a directory called `root`. The problem is that `*.webp` files does not exist when the conversion is performed, so I don't know how to pass their names to `cwebp`. For example, if I only have one picture to convert, I would simple execute

```
cwebp IMG_20160227_110640.jpg -o IMG_20160227_110640.webp
```

However, there are hundreds of them, and I don't want to type hundreds lines of command. How to use a regular expression / write a script to automate the conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` loop combined with parameter expansion:

```
for f in *.jpg; do cwebp "$f" -o "${f%.jpg}.webp"; done
```

See also `LESS='+/Parameter Expansion' man bash` to read up on this for Bash.

However, [Parameter Expansion is specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02); it is not specific to Bash.  (Bash may have some extensions, though.)  The command above will work on any POSIX system.